# input type="image" and input type="button" to draw in html5 canvas, the button is working but i need the image to work

Tags: image, html, canvas, onclick, draw

Hello
What i need to do is when i click an image outside the canvas it calls a javascript function to draw something on the HTML5 canvas.

when i use a button to do this it works fine

```
<input type="button" id="xxx" onclick="draw()"/>
```

but when i use an image

```
<input type="image" id="xxx" onclick="draw()" src="file/sw1.gif"/>
```

the problem is that when i click the image it opens a new page something looks like
 `index.html?x=89&y=8` 
the question is how can i make the image act just like the button without opening a new page?
Thanks

Comment: Better use an image and a absolute positioned input with opacity 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `<img>` tag instead of an image input, because this is not what it was made for.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use an image button to execute Javascript on the `onclick` event.  I think the key is to remove the `action` and `id` attributes from the `form` element.  This (admittedly trivial) code works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="image" value="Submit" onclick="doSomething();" src="html5.png">
        </form>
        <script>
            function doSomething()
            {
                alert("hi mom");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested with FF 5, Chrome 12, Safari 5, and (gasp!) IE 9 (on Win7).